# UNIX/Android low-level API: need to get "Documents" path

Tags: android, api, unix, filesystems, low-level

I need to get the "Documents" path from C code working under Android. The analogs for different OSs are:

*On Windows:*

```
SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_Documents, ...)
```

returns the path to "My Documents" folder.

*On iPhone:*

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

One solution is to call some Android high-level function through JNI (which function, by the way?). But is there a native function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm going to use Android API (through a JNI call) and create the necessary folder for native data. So, it's the function

```
getApplication().getDir("NativeData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath(),
```

that suits me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard "Documents" path in Android.

You can see the standard public directories in the `DIRECTORY_*` constants defined on [the `Environment` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html). AFAIK, there is no way to get the location of those from within the NDK, other than to pass it in from Java -- you get the directory in Java from the `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` method on `Environment`. And none of them are "documents" -- `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` is perhaps the closest match.